# Quick way to go to object's type definition in Goland

Tags: goland

I can do Ctrl+Shift+P (linux) in Goland on a variable name to get the type of object it is (in a tooltip). Is there a quick way to go to the definition of that type? Usually I have to type in the name again (either via search or tapping shift twice).

Comment: Try `CTRL+SHIFT+I` to quickly view the object definition

Comment: That's the definition of the variable. I want to go to the definition of the type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl (Command)</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl (Command)</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Left-click</kbd>.

Please see: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/navigating-through-the-source-code.html#go_to_declaration